# File rename in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I need to rename a file name while upload in codeigniter, by default it create a file name like `sample.png`, `sample1.png` while upload a same file again, but I need to give some authentication to the files uploading with random numbers like `1234_sample.png`, `1232_sample.png`.

Any way to do this. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: Please look into this question...........

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155058/file-rename-while-uploading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller BEFORE you run the actual upload code put the following:

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

As per the CodeIgniter [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

> If set to TRUE the file name will be converted to a random encrypted
>   string. This can be useful if you would like the file saved with a
>   name that can not be discerned by the person uploading it.

This should be put before you run:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config); // need to pass $config array
```

Comment: it is working but it encrypted the file name, but i need to get the file name with random function like below posted by Ultimate

Comment: @jothikannan, are you needing random filenames to prevent people from guessing filenames to access them, or random filenames to prevent the same file from possibly having the same name? The above will solve both situations and be much more random as the strings will be cryptographically generated.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your code but still you can use PHP `rand()` function if you are facing the duplicate name issue:

You can do like this:

```
$file_name=rand(1,1000)."_sample.png";
```

OR

```
$file_name=time()."_sample.png";
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: That helps, but does not ensure there will still not be a duplicate. Usually a timestamp is better for this.

Comment: Using time() does not make it random, but predictable. OP wants the randomness to be there for some low level form of authentication.