# PHP upload issue with code

Tags: php

I keep getting the invalid file error. Can anyone see what is wrong with this script please. I got it from w3 schools and the folder "pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" does exist

```
<?php

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure you're not exceeding the filesize? 2. Do you have write permissions for the upload folder?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` - what are you actually getting?

Comment: W3Schools is erroneous in various places...http://w3fools.com/ 9Since you mentioned that you got the above script from there...

Comment: You should also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads

Comment: start with print_r($_FILES); at the top of your script to see what the data is.

Answer (score 1):

include more error checking like this:

```
<?php

echo process_files();

function process_files()
{
    $allowed_file_types=array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png','image/jpg','image/pjpeg');

    if(0==sizeof($_FILES)) return 'no files uploaded';

    if(!stristr($_FILES['file']['type'], 'image')) return 'file is not an image';

    if(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $allowed_file_types)) return 'image type '.$_FILES['file']['type'].' is not allowed';

    if($_FILES['file']['size'] < 20000) return 'file size too large. Max:20000, File:'.$_FILES['file']['size'];

    // rest of your code here!
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the extension of your pics, maybe are in uppercase