# PHP upload to specific folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to do a php upload that will upload into a specific folder.
One would choose the file they wish to upload next to a dropdown box which is a folder list. This is because it organises files.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["USER"]["Admin"])){
    header("Location: index.html?unath");
}

$folder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loc']);

$target_path = "../../shared/docs/$folder";




$upload2 = $target_path  .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $upload2)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Currently the code uploads the file into the "docs" folder and not docs/folder. Instead it puts the folder name in front of the file. For example- if the folder is called "abc" and my file is called robs.docx it will upload it to the main Docs folder and call it abcrobs.docx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing slash

Replace this line:

```
$upload2 = $target_path  .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

with:

```
$upload2 = $target_path  ."/".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

OR:

Replace this line:

```
$target_path = "../../shared/docs/$folder";
```

with:

```
$target_path = "../../shared/docs/".$folder."/";
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong now.. noob error :) Thanks for that :D

Comment: I will be but I have to wait until stackoverflow lets me

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need `mysql_real_escape_string` because there's no SQL involved here.
2. If no database connection is established, `mysql_real_escape_string` returns `null`. So you're probably throwing away the `$_POST['loc']` value.
3. You should never ever use user supplied values for manipulating anything on the filesystem without really, *really* thorough inspection of what you're going to manipulate. See [Security threats with uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads/11061577#11061577).
4. Use `var_dump` liberally to see what your values look like at various stages and do some debugging.

Comment: I just copied something from an old script for the `$folder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loc']);` At the minute i'm building a rough script which I will develop; for security and duplicate file names. Thanks for the feedback and link

Comment: This upload area is also on a restricted area- only admin users (whom I've authorised) can access- they upload the files to an area where all users on the portal can access (via a webpage)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slash after $target_path

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: `./.` In a way it does answer my question as in I have to look at my code and see where I missed the '/'

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/` on the end of your `$target_path`:

```
$target_path = "../../shared/docs/$folder/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You *should* properly escape your variables:

```
$target_path = "../../shared/docs/". $folder ."/";
```