# php file upload type

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a zip file and a csv file from HTML form.

On PHP, When I printed $_FILES (Actually $request->getFiles() in symfony), I got following.

```
Array
(
    [zipfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => tempfiles.zip
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php5D42.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 850953
        )
    [csvfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.csv
            [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php5D52.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 312
        )
)
```

I'm wondering with the `type` and `tmp_name`. I need to take few decisions based on type. Is it safe to take decisions on existing type? Will I get same result for similar files on Linux server?

Again `tmp_name` have `.tmp` extension. Is it consistent on both windows/linux? If not, is there any way that the code I write on windows (decision using `type`) will work on linux without any issue?

Comment: Very related: [Security threats with uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads/)

Comment: @deceze Sorry but not related. Although I thank you for the good link. I'll definitely go through them in details but my current code code is for admin panel of my site. Thus I'm more concerned about functionality rather than security. Security/best practice is not a question here but making sure it work on both windows/linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this `type` can be dangerous Because user can change the type of the files and can upload a php script.

You should validate the `type` first just like [get_image_size()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to validate a image file.I have no idea about .zip file

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If image should be tested through get_image_size, zip file can be tested through zip_open().

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe to trust the `type` form `$_FILES`, you need to validate the file type in server side.

For `.tmp` extension, it is ok both on windows or linux.

Comment: The `tmp_name` is not guaranteed to end in `.tmp` on every system.

Comment: @deceze That's true, no matter the extension is, it won't be the problem, anyway, the extension name should not be hardcoded.