# How to echo and play videos in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have an application were by users can upload images and should be able to echo and play videos. My upload function works fine but challenge that i am having now is to echo and play the video. Here is how i am uploading the file

```
function uploadFile() {
    $file = $this->data['CpdVideo']['file'];
    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $id = String::uuid();
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files/videos/' . $file['name'])) {
            $this->request->data['CpdVideo']['filename'] = $file['name'];
            $this->request->data['CpdVideo']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
            $this->request->data['CpdVideo']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is how i am saving the video

```
if ($this->uploadFile() && $this->CpdVideo->save($this->data))
```

This how i echo and play the video in my view.ctp. Please not this edited code and this works for me now

```
<object width="100" height="100">
<param name="movie" value="<?php echo $this->Html->url('/files/videos/'. $cpdVideo['CpdVideo']['filename'])?>">
<embed src="<?php echo $this->Html->url('/files/videos/'. $cpdVideo['CpdVideo']['filename'])?>" width="100" height="100">
</embed>
</object>
```

If any one could help me out that would be awesome

Comment: What does `<?php echo $this->Html->media('files/videos'. $cpdVideo['CpdVideo']['filename'], array('fullBase' => true));` print out?

Comment: @yourdeveloperfriend only leaves a space and doesnt print anything.

Comment: Once you got the basic thing working, please do some reading about file upload security - [it's complicated](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload). In your current setup, somebody could just upload their own `.php` and execute it _on your server_, because it is in the public webroot folder.

Comment: Another good starting point about file upload security: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11061577/376138

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying this line

```
<?php echo $this->Html->media('files/videos'. $cpdVideo['CpdVideo']['filename'], array('fullBase' => true));
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->Html->media('files/videos'. $cpdVideo['CpdVideo']['filename'], array('fullBase' => true, type="audio/ogg"));
```

Where ogg is the filetype of that file. The issue is that without that filetype, then some browsers will strip it out of your html (if you view the page source, you may find your audio tag sitting there).

I don't know if CakePHP provides some way to guess the filetype, but it would be worth looking into. I hope I've pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Did you view page source? Does the tag show up there? (page source is different from inspect element btw)

Comment: So it does echo it out? In the page source or in the inspect element?

Comment: now it works changed my video format to swf and i have edited the way i echo the image.