# Php file image upload security

Tags: php

```
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
$extension=strtolower(substr($filename, strpos($filename, '.')+1));
$size=$_FILES['file']['size'];


if(($extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg') && ($type!='image/jpg' || $type!='image/jpeg')){...
```

I have a input file, can let user upload jpg/jpeg image only, I have check type, extension, size.

1. However I'm not sure how to check if user change extension.(ex. abc.php -> abc.jpg)
2. any thing else I need to check before I save user's image into my server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Security threats with uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads)

Comment: @deceze this one is more image specific. there are many php functions that are unique to this question, ie exif_imagetype() and imagejpeg() which should be uniquely beneficial to this situation.

Comment: thx for help, I think i will use all function to check, in case anything happen, looks like there are more articles need to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the image with `exif_imagetype()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

> exif_imagetype() reads the first bytes of an image and checks its
>   signature.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using finfo:

```
<?php
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
        echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);

    /* outputs:
    text/html
    image/gif
    application/vnd.ms-excel
    */
?>
```

example taken from php document site.
see more info on the php document page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: Does this read the MIME type from the file itself somehow, or from the user's Content-Type header?

Comment: @Katana314 Yes from the byte sequences at specific positions within the file please check http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.fileinfo.php :D and its requirements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

@Fabian's answer looks good for checking the type of file.  While I would suggest a different approach to getting the extension of the file.

Consider a file named `stack.overflow.jpg`.

```php
$filename = 'stack.overflow.jpg';

// With your code $extension = 'overflow.jpg'
$extension=strtolower( substr( $filename, strpos( $filename, '.' ) +1 ) );

// With pathinfo() $extension = 'jpg'
$extension = pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
```

Consider using `pathinfo()` to get the file extension: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: file extention means nothing though. I could name my malicious script keyloggervirus.exe.jpg and it would still execute. You need to use PHP to actually verify the image content, like the above answers do.

Comment: is any way to reformate file to jpg? so even its malicious script, it will become jpg

Comment: php has `imagejpeg()`