# Is allowing Photo Upload in website dangerous?

Tags: php, html, security

I want give permission to my users to upload jpg/png type photo using simple  method.. is this dangerous for website.. can someone hack or damage my website with this. i am using PHP in serverside.

Comment: It's always a risk, letting users upload files to your website. But you can mitigate it to a great extent depending on your code. There's no way to say whether your method is safe or not without seeing how you're dealing with it, though.

Comment: This isn't a question. And it isn't dangerous if you do it right.

Comment: which `simple method` do you use?

Comment: simply with php to check photo format and size and pixel..

Answer (score 5):

It's dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

If you don't check that it really is an image, a potential hacker could upload a fully working [C99](http://mikeybeck.com/hacking/) script, and totally wreck your site, even your server.

Basically, what you need to **(at minimum)**, is to use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to check that the uploaded file really is an image.

There's plenty of questions about this at stackoverflow, here's quick and dirty:

```
if (!getimagesize($_FILES['your_image']['tmp_name'])){
    die('Not an image');
}
```

Some excellent advices from @deceze [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads).

If you trust user input, you're eventually going to regret it. Mime-type is easy to fake, I don't even bother to say anything about file extensions.

Some basic rules:

- Never, **ever** trust user input
- Always sanitize your inputs
- If you really need to allow users to upload images, there's [scripts](http://chevereto.com/) already for this, which are much more secure than you can every accomplish.

If you really want to try your luck, for god sake, at least **disable php** in your upload directory and all subdirectories in it.

You can do it by adding a `.htaccess` file in your upload directory containing this.

```
php_flag engine off
```

Comment: *"and totally wreck your site, even your server"* - it's true, and this is why you must never run you PHP script in Apache mod_php (run as Apache's user) but rather as CGI/FCGId wrapper (run as virtual server owner). Then even if it happens you will put in danger only the current web-server and neither other users' accounts nor server itself.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I can agree with that, but it's not always possible (some webhosts). Basically user with access to that script can gain superuser on the server and do anything.

Comment: If you mean *mod_php*, then yes, it's true. In case of *CGI/FCGId* wrappers it wouldn't matter.