# if file_exists() is TRUE give $_FILES["file"]["name"] a unique name using tempnam()

Tags: php

PHP newbie here..

I am trying to create an if statement that will change the name of `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`  to something unique if `file_exists()` comes back true.

My code is given below.. I tried to use `tempnam()` but I'm not 100% sure as to how to implement it using PHP.

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      $_FILES["file"]["name"] = "image/tempnam('',newsFeed)";//this is my problem
      $dialog = $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      }
```

Is there a better way to do this because right now I'm just getting a php error:

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/image/tempnam('',newsFeed)) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

The directory does exist because the upload form works with files that don't have the same name.

Any sort of help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: *Always* give files a unique randomly generated name, not only if it already exists. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11061577/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  $_FILES["file"]["name"] = "image/tempnam('',newsFeed)";
```

With

```
  $_FILES["file"]["name"] = "image/".tempnam('',"newsFeed");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: I replaced it with this instead and it worked. Thanks for the help! 

$_FILES["file"]["name"] = "".tempnam('upload/',newsFeed);

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      $_FILES["file"]["name"] = "image/tempnam('',newsFeed)";//this is my problem
      $dialog = $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      }
```

to

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      $dialog = $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
                         "upload/image/".tempnam('',newsFeed);
}
```